# Is there a way to make all elements in a row class the same height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, is there an easy way to make all the span elements in a row the same height, i.e. the height of the tallest element?

Here's an example of what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/DVnZ6/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery:

```
boxes = $('.well');
maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
  Math, boxes.map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
boxes.height(maxHeight);
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DVnZ6/3/

Comment: @DaveR Short answer: no. Long answer: you could use a fixed height, or, if you've a know number of boxes into a div, use a percentage height (100/N), but it's not the same thing. Take in mind that bootstrap uses jQuery by itself ;)

Comment: @DaveR There's another option, but it works only if you want many divs looks like a table row: http://jsfiddle.net/DVnZ6/2/

Comment: **Substitution** (this works better): .outerHeight() -> .height()

Answer (score 1):

The resize event would have to be added to this code since the height of the content in most cases varies on different resolutions and that produces unwanted design problems like overflowed text.

Here's an more complete version of the code that supports resizing as well

```
jQuery(function () {

    equalMaxWidth = 500; /* Customize viewport width - for resolutions below this number, the height equalizing will not work */
    boxes = jQuery('.well');

    boxes.removeAttr('style');
    if(jQuery(window).width() > equalMaxWidth){
        equalBoxHeights(boxes);
    };

    window.onresize = function () {
        boxes.removeAttr('style');
        console.log( jQuery(window).width());
        if(jQuery(window).width() > equalMaxWidth){
            equalBoxHeights(boxes);
        };
    };
});

function equalBoxHeights(boxes) {
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
            Math, boxes.map(function () {
                return jQuery(this).height();
            }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
}
```

Check the demo on jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/o4w7tjtz/

Tip: try resizing the 3rd vertical frame (noticed equal heights on around 500pw width ?)

Answer (score -3):

If you set the height of the spans to 100% and set the height of the row to a fixed value, they will all match the height of the container.

Of course, you would have to know the expected height of the columns, but it is a js free solution.

Comment: You can't set 100% height on a block element.